# How to read and parse user input specified as a list or a range of numbers

Tags: bash

What is the easiest way to allow user to enter numbers in following formats so that each individual number can be printed.

comma separated ( 1,5,7 ), space separated ( 1 5 7 )  and range separated ( 1-3,5)

```
Expected output if input is comma separated: 
1
5
7
Expected output if input is space separated: 
1
5
7
Expected output if input is - and , separated:
1
2
3
5
```

I have tried following ways, defining logic only

```
input_string="1,5,7"
IFS=' ' read -r -a array <<< "$input_string"
echo ${array[1]} etc..

input_string="1 5 7"
 read -r -a array <<< "$input_string"
echo ${array[1]} etc..
```

Wondering how to handle - and , both together in array , thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split on the commas/spaces first, loop over the results, then split on dashes to get a start and an end for the range:

```
$ cat ranges.sh
#!/bin/bash    
IFS=', ' read -a ranges <<< "$*"
for range in "${ranges[@]}"; do
        IFS=- read start end <<< "$range"
        [ -z "$start" ] && continue
        [ -z "$end" ] && end=$start
        for (( i=start ; i <= end ; i++ )); do
                echo "$i"
        done
done
$ bash ranges.sh 1-3,5 9-10
1       
2               
3       
5
9
10
```

That could do with better sanity checking etc.

Comment: it sounds promising, I tried to use with different input worked well, except trying it with consecutive delimiters adds 0 to output , eg. 1-3,,5 9-10  gives 1 2 3 0 5 9 10.. However as this is not expected in this question and as you mentioned it could do more with some modifications, overall it works well.

Comment: @Bharat, yeah, that's easy to fix by testing if `range` or `start` is empty. But it would also be a good idea to test if `start` and `end` are numbers to begin with.

Comment: yes, it will always be numbers only, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try also

```
T="$@"
echo {1..100} | { cut -d" " -f"${T// /,}"; }
```

Comment: impressing, it works well as least for this input.

Comment: Print all the numbers and let `cut` pick the ones you want? That's has a bit of a Rube Goldberg smell into it, but at least `cut` does sanity checking for the arguments! I can't decide between an upvote for creativity, or a downvote for insanity.

Answer (score 2):

Came up with an Awk Variant

```
awk -v RS='[[:blank:]]|[\n]|[,]' '{max=a[split($0, a ,"-")]; if(max!=0){while(a[1]<=max){print a[1]++}}}' /tmp/a.txt
```

Reading delimited input as a Record,
Splitting it into an array using "-" 
Records without "-" are stored on first index
Finally printing values.

Input:

> 1-3,5 6

Output:

```
1
2
3
5
6
```